# Why is $\int_{X} d(\alpha \wedge *\bar{\beta})$ zero on a compact hermitian manifold?

Tags: manifolds, complex-geometry, stokes-theorem

I am reading the book *Complex Geometry - An Introduction* by Huybrechts. 
In proving *Lemma 3.2.3* that $\partial$ and $\partial^*$ are formal adjoints 
to each other, he mention that the following integral vanishes due to 
Stokes' theorem.
\begin{align}
 \int_{X} d(\alpha \wedge *\bar{\beta})
\end{align}

where $X$ is a compact hermitian manifold, $\alpha$ is of bidegree $(p-1,q)$ and  $\beta$ is of bidegree $(p,q)$.

But shouldn't this equal the integration on the boundary?

A friend of me suggested that maybe the manifold has no boundary. I also found a [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactManifold.html)
which says *the term "compact manifold" often implies "manifold without 
boundary"*. But I am uncomfortable about this idea because I also found the word [closed manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold)
which specifies a compact manifold without boundary.

Also, in case that the manifold has not boundary, I think we can't use Stokes theorem to reason
that the integration is zero right? Roughly, I can think of restricting the integration on a smaller
region which has a boundary. I would get a non-vanishing value on this smaller region. Then I can
grow the region to approximate the value on the whole manifold. It is intuitive unacceptable
for me that the integration finally grows to zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless specifically interested in certain geometric structures (contact manifolds) that arise on the boundaries of certain complex manifolds, it's often strange to think about complex manifolds with boundary - you could go a whole lifetime without doing so. Huybrecht's book doesn't.

Comment: Jost's book Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis makes the same assumption... Didn't realize how a similar form vanished until I saw your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Huybrechts' usage, a manifold does not have boundary. To see this, note that  in Appendix $A$ he defines a chart on an $m$-dimensional manifold to be a pair consisting of an open subset of the manifold, together with a homeomorphism from that open subset to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. For a manifold with boundary, the homeomorphism maps to an open subset of upper half space, not $\mathbb{R}^m$.

By Stokes' Theorem, we have

$$\int_Xd(\alpha\wedge\ast\bar{\beta}) = \int_{\partial X}\alpha\wedge\ast\bar{\beta} = \int_{\emptyset}\alpha\wedge\ast\bar{\beta} = 0.$$

In general, if $X$ is an $n$-dimensional compact manifold (without boundary), then for any $(n-1)$-form $\alpha$,

$$\int_X d\alpha = 0.$$